# How to diff two lines in an open file in vim?

Tags: vim

I occasionally see very long lines in my code that I need to check if they are the same.  Is there a way in vim to select two lines and diff them to show any differences between the two?

For example, given the two lines in vim:

```
AVeryLongReturnType* MyLongClassName:hasAnEvenLongerFunction(That *is, Overloaded *with, Multiple *different, Parameter *lists);
AVeryLongReturnType* MyLongClassName:hasAnEvenLongerFunction(That *is, Overloaded *with, Multiple *different, Parameter *1ists);
```

I would like vim to tell me that the two lines are in fact different because each spells "lists" differently.  Is this possible, and if so, how do I do it?

Comment: If you `:diffthis` (`:difft`) in two buffers, they will be diffed.

Comment: Just noticed this has been copied over to [here](https://code-examples.net/en/q/543697) with no acknowledgement. Don't know if that's breaking any copyright/copyleft but it doesn't seem fair.

Answer (score 52, accepted):

A quick and dirty solution is to just select both lines and sort them while removing duplicates:

- select lines
- ":sort u"
- if only one line remains, both were equal
- if both remain, there most be some difference

An undo recovers everything again.

Comment: That is genius. I've still been wondering about a good clean solution!

Comment: how would you do this, yielding the result in a different split window?

Comment: @serup With "the result" you mean you want to see either either the word "different" or "equal" in a new split window? With the proposed hack I honestly don't see how this could be done without again introducing some helper script which would count the lines before and after the 'second dot' above ... If this number changes, lines were equal, if not then the lines have to be different.

Comment: @CoryKlein I would not call this a "clean" solution, but it does the trick very efficiently :-)

Comment: I like it!  Thanks.

Answer (score 9):

An alternative to @sehe's approach would not require the use of temp files:

```
funct! DiffTwoTexts(text1, text2)
  new
  put =a:text1
  normal ggdd
  diffthis
  new
  put =a:text2
  normal ggdd
  diffthis
endfunct

funct! DiffTwoLines(line1, line2)
  let text1 = getline(a:line1)
  let text2 = getline(a:line2)
  call DiffTwoTexts(text1, text2)
endfunct

comma! DiffWithNext call DiffTwoLines('.', line('.') + 1)
```

This will still be pretty hard to read, since it keeps everything on a single line, so I came up with this modification:

```
funct! EvalTextPreprocessor(expr, text)
  let text = a:text
  return eval(a:expr)
endfunct

comma! -nargs=1 DiffWithNextPre call DiffTwoTexts(
      \ EvalTextPreprocessor(<q-args>, getline('.')),
      \ EvalTextPreprocessor(<q-args>, getline(line('.') + 1)))
```

This new command takes a vimscript expression as its argument, wherein the variable `text` refers to whichever line is being preprocessed.  So you can call, e.g.

```
DiffWithNextPre split(text, '[(,)]\zs')
```

For your sample data, this gives the two buffers

```
AVeryLongReturnType* MyLongClassName:hasAnEvenLongerFunction(
That *is,
 Overloaded *with,
 Multiple *different,
 Parameter *lists)
;
```

and

```
AVeryLongReturnType* MyLongClassName:hasAnEvenLongerFunction(
That *is,
 Overloaded *with,
 Multiple *different,
 Parameter *1ists)
;
```

Only the lines that start with `Parameter` are highlighted.

You can even build up from there, creating a command

```
comma! DiffTwoCFunctionSigs DiffWithNextPre split(text, '[(,)]\s*\zs')
```

Notice that I modified the regexp a bit so that it will keep trailing spaces at the end of lines.  You could get it to ignore them entirely by moving the `\s*` to after the `\zs`.  See `:help /\zs` if you're unfamiliar with what that vim-specific RE atom does.

A nicety would be to make the command take a range (see `:help command-range`), which you could use by diffing the first line of the range with the last line.  So then you just visual-select from the first line to the second and call the command.

Comment: thanks for showing examples of creating commands that take arguments. I'm a bit overwhelmed (my answer was my first ever vim script beyond setting options in vimrc...)

Comment: @sehe: It's probably a lot to take in, yeah :)  If you make a file `~/.vim/plugins/diff_two_lines.vim` and put the code in there, you will have those commands available whenever you use vim.  Or actually, you can just put them in your .vimrc; making it a plugin is just a little more organized.  Remember that you'll have to restart vim (or `:source` your script) to make the commands work.

Answer (score 9):

I used [linediff.vim](https://vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=3745).

*This plugin provides a simple command, **":Linediff"**, which is used to diff two separate blocks of text.*

Comment: The URL for this plugin is rather this one, if I'm not wrong:
https://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=3745

Answer (score 7):

That is not a feature, however it is easily scripted, e.g. in your vimrc:

```
function! DiffLineWithNext()
    let f1=tempname()
    let f2=tempname()

    exec ".write " . f1
    exec ".+1write " . f2

    exec "tabedit " . f1
    exec "vert diffsplit " . f2
endfunction
```

This will open the current and next lines in vertical split in another tab.
Note that this code is a sample

- it doesn't check whether next line exists (there are any following lines)
- it doesn't cleanup the tempfiles created
- a nice improvement would be to take a range, or use the `''` mark to select the *other* line

You can leave off the 'vert' in order to have a horizontal split

Map it to something fancy so you don't have to `:call` it manually:

```
:nnoremap <F10> :call DiffLineWithNext()^M
```

Comment: Great answer! Are the ampersands in front of the variable names really necessary?

Comment: @MatthiasBraun Oops. No, it appears I had some misunderstandings about Vim Script back in 2011! Fixed.

Comment: :-) I see. Is there a reason why you wrapped all commands in `exec`s now? I'm just curious and like to learn more about Vim script.

Comment: @MatthiasBraun Yes. Just start somewhere like here http://learnvimscriptthehardway.stevelosh.com/ (my original code actually created files named `&f1` and `&f2` instead of using `tempname()` by mistake)

Answer (score 4):

you could also just create a new empty window buffer and copy line, then make command:

```
:windo diffthis
```

this should open a new window showing the differences of those 2 lines